# Wrapper Class With Test Class with code coverage to complete?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, code-coverage

I've got a line of code that I can't cover in my tests:

[image]
Any idea of how I can cover this?

**Apex Class:**

```
public class wrapperclass_1 {
public list<wrapperclass> wrapperlist{set;get;}
public list<wrapperclass> wrapperlist1{set;get;}
public list<Account> acclist{set;get;}
public list<account> selectedacc{set;get;}
public list<contact> conlist{set;get;}
public list<contact> selectedcon{set;get;}
public wrapperclass_1()
{
wrapperlist=new list<wrapperclass>();
wrapperlist1=new list<wrapperclass>();
acclist=[select id,name,rating,annualrevenue from account limit 5];
conlist=[select id,name,email,phone from contact limit 5];
for(account a:acclist)
{
wrapperclass w=new wrapperclass();
w.cbox=false;
w.acc=a;
wrapperlist.add(w);
}
for(contact c:conlist)
{
wrapperclass w1=new wrapperclass();
w1.cbox=false;
w1.con=c;
wrapperlist1.add(w1);
}
}
//5
public void selectedrec()
{
selectedacc=new list<account>();
for(wrapperclass wc:wrapperlist)
{
if(wc.cbox==true)
selectedacc.add(wc.acc);
}
}
public class wrapperclass{
public boolean cbox{set;get;}
public account acc{set;get;}
public contact con{set;get;}
public wrapperclass()
{
acc=new account();
}
}
}
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperclass_1">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperlist}" var="w">
<apex:column >
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!w.cbox}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column value="{!w.acc.name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!w.acc.rating}"/>
<apex:column value="{!w.acc.annualrevenue}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:commandButton value="Selected Record" action="{!selectedrec}"/>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedacc}" var="a">
<apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!a.rating}"/>
<apex:column value="{!a.annualrevenue}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**TestClass:**

```
@istest(seealldata=true)
public class wrapperclass_1_Tc{
//public boolean cbox{set;get;}
static testmethod void wrapperclass_1_Tc()
{
account a=new account(name='xxx',rating='xxx',annualrevenue=888);
insert a;
wrapperclass_1 w1=new wrapperclass_1();
w1.selectedrec();
}
}
```

**Image:**

Comment: can you be specific on what's your issue and give more details on your question, also you are missing the image.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `wrapperclass_1` code you included in the question, that line requires at least one item in the `wrapperlist` to have a true `cbox` value. So one of your test methods will need to look something like this:

```
static testmethod void cbox() {
    insert new account(name='xxx', rating='xxx', annualrevenue=888);
    wrapperclass_1 w1 = new wrapperclass_1();
    for (wrapperclass wc : w1.wrapperlist) {
        wc.cbox = true;
    }
    w1.selectedrec();
    System.assertEquals(w1.wrapperlist.size(), w1.selectedacc.size());
}
```

Don't get too hung up on code coverage: tests that cover 90% of the code but assert all the required behaviour are better than tests that cover 100% of the code but don't assert all the required behaviour. Focus on checking that the code works in your tests and the coverage will happen as a side effect.

But before adding more tests, I suggest you should first improve the names you are using in your code. Generally it is better to use names from the problem domain.

Also `@istest(seealldata=true)` is best avoided and is not needed in your tests.