# I have written a test class for wrapper class code coverage is 95%?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm trying to write test coverage for an apex class with a inner wrapper class, but one line isn't getting covered, any pointers for getting this line covered?

#### ApexClass

```
public class TestWrapperClass {
    public list<wrapperclassex> wrapperlist{set;get;}
    public list<account> acclist{set;get;}
    public list<account> selectedacc{set;get;}
    public TestWrapperClass()
    {
        acclist=[select id,name,rating from account limit 5];
        wrapperlist=new list<wrapperclassex>();
        for(account a:acclist)
        {
            wrapperclassex w=new wrapperclassex();
            w.cbox=false;
            w.acc=a;
            wrapperlist.add(w);
        }
    }
    public void selectedrec()
    {
        selectedacc=new list<account>();
        for(wrapperclassex w1:wrapperlist)
        {
            if(w1.cbox==true)
            {
                selectedacc.add(w1.acc);
            }
        }
    }
    public class wrapperclassex{
        public boolean cbox{set;get;}
        public account acc{set;get;}
    }
}
```

#### Test Class

```
@istest
public class TestWrapperClass_Tc {
    static testmethod void TestWrapperClass_Tc() {
        account a= new account(name='xxx', rating='xxx', annualrevenue=888);
        insert a;
        TestWrapperClass w1 = new TestWrapperClass();
        //  for (wrapperclassex  wc :wrapperlist) {
        //   wc.cbox = true;
        //}
        w1.selectedrec();
        System.assertEquals(w1.wrapperlist.size(), w1.selectedacc.size());
    }
}
```

#### Code coverage image

[image]

Comment: Look at the answer to the previous posting of this question [Wrapper Class With Test Class with code coverage to complete?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78116/wrapper-class-with-test-class-with-code-coverage-to-complete).

Comment: it is throwing an error here just check it once

Comment: for (wrapperclass wc : w1.wrapperlist) {
        wc.cbox = true;
    }

Comment: @frz.sfdc welcome to salesforce stack exchange, to get a good answer you'll need to clean up your question a bit so it's asking a specific question, as opposed to just asking to write your test class. I've taken a stab at updating it

Comment: i need to cover whole completed code to 100%

Comment: @frz.sfdc code coverage is just a measure, you need to cover the use cases, it looks like you might want to spend some time doing the tutorials on trailhead and also consider looking at java coding conventions as your code was very poorly formatted and hard to read before my edits

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code the line that's not getting covered is because your test class doesn't have any instance of `WrapperClassex` that has a `cbox` value of `true`. Because of the condition `if(w1.cbox == true)` never returns the next line will never get called.

You need to update your test so that an instance of your wrapper class meets the criteria.

Comment: could u write that line update

Comment: @frz.sfdc no, writing code for you isn't what this forum is for